# WAMP on Windows 7 won't start. Apache error "Illegal override option Require"

Tags: apache, wamp

WAMP logo remains orange and won't go green. I've identified via looking at the Services that it's Apache that won't start. But I can't get it to start. MySQL is started and running fine.

And I had WAMP running fine for several weeks. This just cropped up today.

It's not a Port 80 / Skype issue, which are well documented, as I can test Port 80 just fine, and it's not in use.

How to troubleshoot a little deeper to figure out why WAMP apache won't start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your answer I see what you did, but it is in fact wrong.

That section of code should look like this

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none 
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

This is the instruction that sets Apache's base rights on the servers root folder and should be set to `denied`. You start by denying access to everything and then allow access only to folder that Apache should actually be allowed to see, for obvious security reasons.

The probable reason for your issue was that you looked at httpd.conf using notepad and that somehow removed the line break after `AllowOverride all` making it into a illegal parameter i.e. 2 seperate instructions on the same line.

For some odd reason WAMPServer 2.5 got released with some files having UNIX line ending rather than DOS line endings! And this is why notepad has problems with them.

Best idea is to download notepad++ ( its free ) and can cope with files that have unix line endings.

It would probably be useful to [read through this document](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685) on the WAMPServer forum called "WAMPServer 2.5 release notes and corrections"

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the correction! That would explain why nowhere on the interwebs was the string "AllowOverride all Require" found.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after finding some help, I've solved the issue. It was an apache config error. I'm still not certain what caused it, but here's how I solved it if it crops up for you.

By using CMD from inside the wamp directory, I saw the error was in the httpd.conf file. I was able to open that file up in my code editor (Notepad doesn't show line breaks, so it's impossible to read), and there I simply removed the offending code.

The steps to solve apache config errors:

1. Use command line (CMD) to access the wamp apache directory (use `x:` to change drives to drive `x` if needed) at *\bin\apache\apache2.x.x\bin*
2. Run `httpd.exe -S` to ask apache to validate the httpd.conf file
3. Read error that is returned, if any. Identify the line number, file, and error.
4. Open the *apache2.x.x\conf\httpd.conf* file in your code editor, go to the offending line, and change the offending code.

In this case, the validation routine returned:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 241 of V:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/httpd.conf:  
Illegal override option Require
```

I opened my httpd.conf file, and found on line 240:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I simple removed the `Require all denied` bit, saved the conf file, started Apache, and voila. I don't understand what that option was intended to do, or how it got set, but wamp is running like a charm now that it's removed.